# AngularJs with seperate state does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

code like this.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('site', {
        abstract:'true',
        views: {
            'header': {
                templateUrl: 'scripts/header/header.html',
                controller: 'HeaderController'
            },
            '': {
                template: '<div ui-view></div>'
            }
        }
    });

$stateProvider.state('main', {
    url: "",
    parent: "site",
    views: {
        "": {
            templateUrl: "scripts/app/main/main.html",
            controller: "MainController"
        },
        'header': {
            templateUrl: 'scripts/app/header/header.html',
            controller: 'HeaderController'
        }
    }
});
```

and the index.html is like

```
<body class="container">
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

actually, I test by removing bellow code, it works.content in 'site' state can be insert into the index.html 'header' ui-view and the empty ui-view part. So I guess that's something wrong with bellow code part.But what's wrong? I cannot figure it out.

```
$stateProvider.state('main', {
    url: "",
    parent: "site",
    views: {
        "": {
            templateUrl: "scripts/app/main/main.html",
            controller: "MainController"
        },
        'header': {
            templateUrl: 'scripts/app/header/header.html',
            controller: 'HeaderController'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your 2nd ui-view is does not match the url that you are attempting to use for your state. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: @Evan Bechtol, I update the code for accuracy. About your post, how to correct the code?

Comment: You need to initialize the `ui-view` directive properly by giving it a name. Also, open your developer tools in the browser and check for errors in the console.

Comment: @Evan Bechtolm, I've did that when testing the code except that give a name to the inner ui-view in index.html or the 'site' '': {
                template: '<div ui-view></div>'
            }, because do not need to do that.

Comment: Do you get any errors on your developer console